# Looping through a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, streamreader

I'm currently working on a project where I have to calculate the number of people that had treatment and follow ups. All the data is stored in a file and then it is displayed in a ListView. Is there a method to loop through the listview and then count the fields that required follow ups and display the number in a text box.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("INCIDENT.txt"))
{
    int iCount = 0;

    while(sr.Peek() != -1)
    {
        ListViewItem lvRead = new ListViewItem();
        lvRead.Text = sr.ReadLine();
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lvRead.SubItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        lstViewData.Items.Add(lvRead);

        iCount++;
    }
}
```

Or is there any way I can loop through the file and jump from 4 to 4 lines and then count the total number of people that needed follow up?

This is how my file looks like:

```
1001
Alex
Staff
wounded knee
Sunderland
Yes
bandage
No
```

Comment: `lvRead.SubItems.Count` ?

Comment: yeah, but the thing is I want to count, let's say the Follow Up column which has Yes or No, how to i make sure that I am at the right column ?

Comment: I think something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) could help you. There is also an example on how to use it in the article

Comment: Thanks, but the this is I'm kind of new to C# so this is pretty difficult for me to understand, have you got an easier way to do it?

Comment: *"how to i make sure that I am at the right column"* - because of chosen format it's impossible. Because `1001` could be a text or number and could be content of any column. Consider to use another format to serialize data, e.g. json. Then you would be able to map column name to value.

Comment: You need to properly parse the text file.  You are just grabbing lines from the source file which has a structure and you need to parse the structure to get the lines you want.

Comment: jdweng, can you help me with that? please